# Loading controller on demand using AngularJS and RequireJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular UI-router and trying to download/load controller when the routing changes. I used resolve and category, the data.data returns the js file content as string. I'm not sure to make the controller available to angular. Please help

My module.js contains below routing code

```
state("privacy", {
        url: "/privacy",
        controllerProvider: function ($stateParams) {
            return "PrivacyController";
        },
        resolve: {
            category: ['$http', '$stateParams', function ($http, $stateParams) {
                return $http.get("js/privacy.js").then(function (data) {
                    return data.data;
                });
            } ]
        },
        templateUrl: localPath + "templates/privacy.html"
    })
```

The below controller exist in "js/privacy.js"

> socialinviter.controller("PrivacyController", function ($scope) {
>   $scope.me = "Hellow world";
>   });

I also tried with require js but I'm getting error "http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=PrivacyController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined"

```
resolve: {
            deps: function ($q, $rootScope) {
                var deferred = $q.defer(),
                    dependencies = ["js/privacy"];
                    require(dependencies, function () {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        });
                        deferred.resolve()
                    })
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is `PrivacyController` defined inside data.data?

Comment: PrivacyController is defined on a separate file, the $http.get is downloading that file and the data.data contains socialinviter.controller("PrivacyController", function ($scope) { $scope.me = "Hellow world"; });

Comment: You cannot do that. You are just downloading a file..

Comment: I also tried with requirejs, see the above code, it download the file but it throws error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue and I thought the solution would be helpful for others

Step 1: On your config, include the parameter $controllerProvider

```
mytestapp.config(function ($stateProvider, $controllerProvider)
```

Step 2: telling angular to register the downloaded controller as controller, add the below inside the config

```
mytestapp.config(function ($stateProvider, $controllerProvider) {
mytestapp._controller = mytestapp.controller
mytestapp.controller = function (name, constructor){
    $controllerProvider.register(name, constructor);
    return (this);
}
......
```

Step 3: Add the resolve method as below

```
state("privacy", {
        url: "/privacy",
        controller: "PrivacyController",
        resolve: {
            deps : function ($q, $rootScope) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                require(["js/privacy"], function (tt) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });
                    deferred.resolve()
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        },
        templateUrl: "templates/privacy.html"
    })
```